# Is it possible to access child object properties from a List of a base object?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I have a base Message objects and then many more specific Message objects that inherit from the Message object. I want to be able to store some messages into a List of Lists. I need to be able to find the index of the outer List where there is a certain child message with a particular property value. (For my specific project, the order in which I add the messages to the List is always the same, so I will know which message is at which index.)

```
namespace Project
{
    public class Message {} //base class
}
```

Here's two example child Messages:

```
class ABCMessage : Message
{
    public ABCMessage() { }

    public string ABCproperty1 { get; set; }
    public string ABCProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string ABCProperty3 { get; set; }
}


class XYZMessage : Message
{
    public XYZMessage() { }

    public string XYZproperty1 { get; set; }
    public string XYZProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

And here is what I want to do:

```
public static List<List<Message>> MessageList;

ABCMessage abcMessage = new ABCMessage();
abcMessage.ABCProperty1 = 1;
abcMessage.ABCProperty2 = 2;
abcMessage.ABCProperty3 = 3;
List<Message> myList = new List<Message>();
myList.Add(abcMessage);

//...

int index;
for (int i = 0; i < MessageList.Count; i++) {
    if (MessageList[i][0].ABCProperty2 == 5) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, the problem is that I'm not able to call that property (or any property for that matter). Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Perhaps do I need to put properties in my Message class? (The only reason I wanted to do inheritance was to make it easier to make a List of Lists.)

Comment: How about `for (...) { if (MessageList[i][0] is ABCMessage && ((ABCMessage)MessageList[i][0]).ABCProperty2 == 5) { index = i; break; } }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to cast each message to `ABCMessage` and then, if not null, it's a instance of `ABCMessage` and so can have it's properties tested:

```
int index;
for (int i = 0; i < MessageList.Count; i++) 
{
    var message = MessageList[i][0] as ABCMessage;
    if (message != null && message.ABCProperty2 == 5) 
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

As not everyone likes the `as`/test for null approach, the other option is to use `is`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MessageList.Count; i++) 
{
    var message = MessageList[i][0] as ABCMessage;
    if (MessageList[i][0] is ABCMessage && (ABCMessage)(MessageList[i][0]).ABCProperty2 == 5) 
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, as of C# 6, a  new option (the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx) or "Elvis operator" as it's also known) exists, that uses the best of both worlds:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MessageList.Count; i++)
{
    var message = MessageList[i][0] as ABCMessage;
    if (message?.ABCProperty2 == 5)
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

The `message?.ABCProperty2 == 5` syntax only tests `ABCProperty2` if `message` is not null, removing the need for the `!= null` test.

Comment: I tried the second and third options you gave, but neither of them worked. However, the first option you gave works great.